# Word for know-in-advance true

Tags: word-usage

Is there such a word for describing question which is asked by someone who just wants to hear your answer on it something like rhetorical queation.

Let's say you told your friend that you will be on basketball court but actually you hanged around with another friends and that one friend saw you after which he calls you again to ask what you do.

Comment: Why not "rhetorical question"?

Comment: @gotube I don't think it's suitable enough in that understanding.

Comment: Is the purpose of this question to make someone look bad?

Comment: @gotube at some point it is, but not only, since you don't know that friend knows true

Comment: So the reason for asking the question is for other people to hear the answer? Like, if a parent knows what their child did, but still asks in front of the other parent so they can hear the answer?

Comment: @gotube yes, it's like also note for yourself to see if one going to lie or tell truth afterwards keeping in mind that maybe his plans changed for the day and that's why he went to hang around, but in the end he simply lied.

Comment: I think it depends on your reason for asking the question. If, similar to what @gotube is saying, it is to probe if someone is lying, then you might want to look into the concept of "Volatile Conundrum". I don't think that's the word you're looking for, but it's what that kind of question is trying to create. Good question by the way -- I'm intrigued to see what the final answer is!

Comment: There are lots of possible options: *trick question*, *Socratic question*, *dishonest question*, *rhetorical question*, *fake question*, and others. It depends entirely on context and nuance, so your question is going to have to get more specific, but if I go by your one example, from what I can surmise, that's called a "trick question."

Comment: There are lots of possible options: *trick question*, *Socratic question*, *dishonest question*, *rhetorical question*, *fake question*, and others. It depends entirely on context and nuance, so your question must get more specific, but if I go by your one example, from what I can surmise, that's called a "trick question," a deceptive question for which the answer is known, which is asked to test the answerer to see if the answerer will lie again, to trick the answerer into lying so as to then trap the answerer in that lie, and/or to force a confession out of or shame the answerer.